# HTML - text on image without css possible? and how?

Tags: html

I just got an commission from school, to put an text above an image without using css or anithing similar to it, it has to be done all by HTML and in a table. I got this by now. On the image URL 
http://snag.gy/6NvWq.jpg
 and Support http://snag.gy/Amh7N.jpg need to go some text above it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mailing</title>  
    <meta name="author" content="Ronald Dewindt">
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="images/parksenz.jpg" alt="Parksenz"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p style="color:rgb(110,110,110);">Geachte klant,</p>
                <p style="color:rgb(110,110,110);">Voor uw e-mail is een reset link aangevraagd voor het wijzigen van het e-mailadres bij Green-parking. Gebruik onderstaande link om het e-mailadres te bevestigen. U moet daarna met uw gewijzigde e-mailadres inloggen.</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="images/@Logo.jpg" alt="@"><img src="images/urlZondertekst.jpg" alt="Url_webbrowser"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p>Klik hier om uw wachtwoord opnieuw in te stellen of kopieer en plak deze URL in de webbrowser: {$CallbackUrl}</p></td>

        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td><p style="color:rgb(110,110,110);">Hartelijk dank dat u Greenparking gebruikt.</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p style="color:rgb(110,110,110);">Met vriendelijke groet,</p>
                <p style="color:rgb(110,110,110);">Het team van Greenparking</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="images/supportZondertekst.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="images/footerImage.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_body_background.asp

Comment: Add a fiddle with your example code and working image. This helps others to help you even better. Can you illustrate the desired result in an example image?

Comment: best way to put text on an image without using css is to put the text in the image itself otherwise you will need to use css.  Also tables are for tabular data only (unless making an email template)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the attribute "background" in your td elements, but you have to know that it is a bad practice and **this attribute is deprecated in HTML5**.

Example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td background="images/parksenz.jpg">Parksenz</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

*Please, tell your teacher to teach you some CSS.*

Comment: i already got the answer but thx anyways, He meant to cut the first side of the image where you dont have letters and than to give the other size a background color. and btw i know css the only thing is he was challenging me to see how i would do something like that.